# Изменение размера картинки в блоке

Tags: html, css, layout, float

Есть макет вида:

```
<div class="left">
text
</div>
<div class="right">
text
</div>
<div class="center">
<img....>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
float: left;
width: 303px;
padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.right {
float: right;
width: 425px;
padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.center {
padding: 0 40px;
text-align: center;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

При уменьшении окна браузера блок с изображением уходит вниз.
Каким образом можно уменьшать изображение при уменьшении размеров окна браузера средствами css?

Пробовал стиль изображения

```
.center img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Не помогает.

Comment: 1) https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/2gwuuwL2/1/ 2) https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/2gwuuwL2/

Comment: @soledar10 А насколько flex кроссбраузерен?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Проценты высчитываются относительно родительского блока, а его у вас нет. Добавьте блоку .center стиль position:relative; и тогда изображение не будет выходить за его пределы.

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 303px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 425px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.center {
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;

  position:relative;
}

.center img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">text</div>
<div class="right">text</div>
<div class="center"><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg'/></div>
```